# What does "OBJECTIONABLE" indicate on a VFR chart?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, symbology

On the [Tulsa, Oklahoma VFR sectional](http://skyvector.com/?ll=36.186880306392254,-95.88262939757304&chart=301&zoom=1) the top of the outer Class C ring says "OBJECTIONABLE". Does this indicate some information on the chart is in dispute? I don't see anything in the VFR chart legend or side panels about the meaning.

[image]

Comment: It's highly unlikely that this designation has anything to do with Tulsa's class C. It's much more likely that it applies to one or more of the private fields ([see here](http://expertaviator.com/2012/07/31/what-is-an-objectionable-airport/)).

Comment: I object! This airspace is out of order and furthermore is antagonizing my Certification as a professional pilot!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means that the airspace around the airport is still under review after a proposed change.

This article explains it in more detail: http://expertaviator.com/2012/07/31/what-is-an-objectionable-airport/

And here's the official text: [Part 157](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=dcd99a685fc7b1dcde1663cbc9b6884c&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:3.0.1.3.27&idno=14)

> §157.7   FAA determinations. (a) The FAA will conduct an aeronautical
>   study of an airport proposal and, after consultations with interested
>   persons, as appropriate, issue a determination to the proponent and
>   advise those concerned of the FAA determination. The FAA will consider
>   matters such as the effects the proposed action would have on existing
>   or contemplated traffic patterns of neighboring airports; the effects
>   the proposed action would have on the existing airspace structure and
>   projected programs of the FAA; and the effects that existing or
>   proposed manmade objects (on file with the FAA) and natural objects
>   within the affected area would have on the airport proposal. While
>   determinations consider the effects of the proposed action on the safe
>   and efficient use of airspace by aircraft and the safety of persons
>   and property on the ground, the determinations are only advisory.
>   Except for an objectionable determination, each determination will
>   contain a determination-void date to facilitate efficient planning of
>   the use of the navigable airspace. A determination does not relieve
>   the proponent of responsibility for compliance with any local law,
>   ordinance or regulation, or state or other Federal regulation.
>   Aeronautical studies and determinations will not consider
>   environmental or land use compatibility impacts.
>
> (b) An airport determination issued under this part will be one of the
>   following:
>
> (1) No objection.
>
> (2) Conditional. A conditional determination will identify the
>   objectionable aspects of a project or action and specify the
>   conditions which must be met and sustained to preclude an
>   objectionable determination.
>
> (3) **Objectionable. An objectionable determination will specify the
>   FAA's reasons for issuing such a determination**.
>
> (c) Determination void date. All work or action for which notice is
>   required by this sub-part must be completed by the determination void
>   date. Unless otherwise extended, revised, or terminated, an FAA
>   determination becomes invalid on the day specified as the
>   determination void date. Interested persons may, at least 15 days in
>   advance of the determination void date, petition the FAA official who
>   issued the determination to:
>
> (1) Revise the determination based on new facts that change the basis
>   on which it was made; or
>
> (2) Extend the determination void date. Determinations will be
>   furnished to the proponent, aviation officials of the state concerned,
>   and, when appropriate, local political bodies and other interested
>   persons.

Comment: In this case the culprit is [OK94 ("Sand Ridge Airpark")](http://skyvector.com/airport/OK94/Sand-Ridge-Airpark-Inc-Airport), which has been deemed "Objectionable" because it conflicts with approaches to Tulsa International.

Comment: I believe that your opening statement, `It means that the airspace around the airport is still under review after a proposed change`, is incorrect. I believe the label, `OBJECTIONABLE`, indicates that the FAA *has* made the airspace determination.

Comment: @JonathanWalters Not quite. It's more like a hint to what the FAA wants to do with the airspace and the public can object to that preliminary decision.

Comment: @voretaq7: Seems like they've worked out their problems, since Sand Ridge no longer shows up on the sectional as "OBJECTIONABLE".

Answer (score 13):

According to the FAA Aeronautical Navigation Products [FAQ](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/faq/index.cfm?print=go#q3d):

> **What does "OBJECTIONABLE" stand for on VFR Charts?**
>
> "OBJECTIONABLE" indicates an airspace determination per FAA Joint
>   Order 7400.2J Section 4, Airport Charting and Publication of Airport
>   Data, issued 9 FEB 2012. When you see this indication on a chart be
>   sure to refer to the applicable Airport/Facility Directory for more
>   information. FAA Regional Airports Offices are responsible for
>   airspace determinations. Address any challenges to objectionable
>   airspace determinations to your regional airports office.

[**FAA Joint Order 7400.2J**](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/AIR.pdf) Section 4 refers to Airport Airspace Analysis and says (emphasis added by me):

> **10−1−1. PURPOSE**
>
> a. This part provides guidelines, procedures, and standards that
>   supplement those contained in 14 CFR part 157, Notice of Construction,
>   Alteration, Activation, and Deactivation of Airports.
>
> b. These guidelines, procedures, and standards ***must be used in
>   determining the effect construction, alteration, activation, or
>   deactivation of an airport will have on the safe and efficient use of
>   the navigable airspace by aircraft***.
>
> **10−4−1. POLICY**
>
> a. All landing facilities which have received airspace determinations
>   or those not analyzed, must be properly documented and processed in
>   accordance with procedures contained in FAAO 5010.4, Airport Safety
>   Data Program.
>
> b. ***Landing facilities that have received objectionable airspace
>   determinations must be published in the NFDD as “objectionable.”*** They
>   must be depicted on VFR aeronautical charts only and without
>   identifying text other than to designate objectionable status. They
>   must not be published in the Airport/Facility Directory (A/FD).