# Why are some non-towered airports charted with an empty circle?

Tags: airport, usa, aeronautical-charts

[image]

Guntly Memorial Airport (62C) is shown as an empty circle with four hash marks around the edges. Why is it empty versus some of the other airports around (such as 96C, C89, BUU, etc.) that have a depiction of the runways inside a magenta circle?

Also, do the hash marks around an empty circle mean the usual - that there are fuel services available at that airport?

Answer (score 9):

Your first stop for questions like this should be the [FAA Aeronautical Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/). In the *VFR Sectional & TAC* section it says:

> Runway patterns will be depicted at airports with at least one hard surfaced runway 1500´ or greater in length.

If you look up the details for 62C in the Chart Supplement or [whatever other source you like](https://aopa.org/destinations/airports/62C/details), you can see it has two grass runways, i.e. no hard surfaced runways.

As for the hash marks, they do mean that fuel is available.

Answer (score 0):

The other airport on this chart that does not have runways is labeled “[OBJECTIONABLE](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/faq/#q3d)”. It may or may not have hard-surface runways but:

> The type “OBJECTIONABLE” associated with an airport symbol indicates
>   that an objectionable airspace determination has been made for the
>   airport per FAA Order JO 7400.2 Section 4, Airport Charting and
>   Publication of Airport Data. Objectionable airspace determinations can
>   be based upon a number of factors including conflicting traffic
>   patterns with another airport, hazardous runway conditions, or natural
>   or man-made obstacles in close proximity to the landing area. FAA
>   Regional Airports Offices are responsible for airspace determinations.

Comment: This designation is covered in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1282/62), although I'm not sure what it has to do with the airport chart symbol?

Comment: @Pondlife I was just pointing out that there are some rare cases when the empty circle does not give any indication about the type or length of the runway.